# Appending a value from dialog box to HTML body

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a problem of appending a value from the textbox in the dialog box to my html body.

```
<div id="dialog-form">
  <form>
    <label for="name">Name</label>
     <input type="text" name="name" id="txt2 codein" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all" />
  </form>
</div>
<p>Please are you <span id="addname"></span>

setTimeout( function() {

$( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
    modal: true,
    draggable: false,
    height: 300,
    width: 500,
    open: function () {
      $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');
    },
});

},4000);

var keeptrying = function(e) {
var addmust = $('#dialog-form #codein').val();

$("#addname").append("#dialog-form #codein");
}
```

Any help and answer is appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go with the solution https://jsfiddle.net/g9m1pqmu/

```
setTimeout( function() {
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
        modal: true,
        draggable: false,
        height: 300,
        width: 500,
        open: function () {
            $('body').addClass('stop-scrolling');
        }
    });
},4000);

$('#codein').keypress(function() {
    $("#addname").html($('#codein').val());
});
```

I guess this is what you are looking for.

Comment: Tnx man its pretty working. but it does not add the last letter in the textbox, is there any other way of solving that. I appreciate your work.

Comment: If your requirement is same then I don't think you will have any other alternative to solve it.

Comment: ok thanks for the ones u did for me. hoping to know you more < }